# Quadratic formula not working in Quantum Mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

In quantum mechanics the raising operator of a system with quantum number $s$ and $m$ is such that $$\hat{S}^+|s,m\rangle = \hbar \sqrt{s(s+1)-m(m+1)}|s,m+1\rangle$$

Since there must exists a $m_\text{max}$ where $$\hat{S}^+|s,m_\text{max}\rangle = \hbar \sqrt{s(s+1)-m_\text{max}(m_\text{max}+1)}|s,m_\text{max}\rangle = 0$$ Hence to obtain the solutions we must solve:

$$s(s+1)=m_\text{max}(m_\text{max}+1)$$
At first glance it is easy to recognise that one of the solution is $$m_\text{max} = s$$
Now although the second solution isn't so obvious, it can be found by factorising:
$$m_\text{max}^2+m_\text{max}-s(s+1)=0$$
so that
$$(m_\text{max}+(s+1))(m_\text{max} - s)=0$$
with second solution
$$m_\text{max} = -(s+1)$$
If I try to solve the same equation using a quadratic formula, I find that
$$m_\text{max} = \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4s(s+1)}}{2}$$

My question is: In this case, why does the quadratic formula not give me solutions of the form
$$m_\text{max}=-(s+1)$$
$$m_\text{max}=s$$

Am I missing something simple?Shouldn't the quadratic formula works for all quadratic equations?

Comment: Are you so sure that these two results are different? Have you tried plugging in some numbers and checking?

Comment: both solutions give the same quadratic equation, my question is just why doesn't the quadratic formula give solutions in the same form as the factorising one.

Comment: Please don't remove the [tag:homework-and-exercises] tag from this post. Thanks!

Comment: This wasn't a homework or exercise, although it may look like it because the steps were easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does. All you need to do is  to transform
$$
\sqrt{1+4s(s+1)}
=
\sqrt{4s^2+4s+1}
=
\sqrt{(2s+1)^2}
=
2s+1
$$
(since $s\geq0$) and work out the rest of the algebra.

Comment: Ohh my bad I didn't spot that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$1 + 4 s (s + 1) = 4 s^2 + 4s + 1 = (2s + 1)^2$, so as @knzhou pointed out this indeed gives the same solutions.